# How to store data of different type's in one single file?

Tags: c#, file-io, containers

#### Problem

For my current project, i need to store images, serialized objects and so on, within a single file with an underlining file-structure. This whole procedure is new to me, because of my php background.

#### Question

What are good reads to that topic and what is the "best practice" for those kind of things?

#### Remark

The user should still be able to manipulate the data, i he/she likes to.

Comment: what do you mean by *The user should still be able to manipulate the data*? Edit the resulting file directly? How would they edit a serialized object or image saved there?

Comment: I thought of using a zip file as container, the content will still be editable, the user just has to override the existing files, i.e. the xml will still be plain-text and the images still be images.

Comment: ZIP or similar archive is not a bad idea.  Take a look at this github project for related ideas (virtual file system): https://github.com/platformdotnet/Platform.VirtualFileSystem

Comment: I'll probably take the Platform.VirtualFileSystem approach, thanks @david-tansey. If you like, add your recommendation to the answers and you can get some rep ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you awnt the user be able to *patch* the files you should use some form of text file (as opposed to a binary file).

There are two very popular file formats used for tasks like yours: XML and JSON. For both file formats exist large and rich libraries.

Inherently binary data like pictures need to be serialized to some text format (like base64) before you can add it as a single element to such files.

These files are editable with a simple text editor.

Comment: As i commented on the main question, i would prefer to use a sort of container that is user friendly, i.e. a zip file or something along the line.

Comment: Well, yes, but this will force your users to use additional software (e.g. WinZip) to manipulate the file.

Comment: Windows has build-in zip capabilities, i.e. this wont be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

For this you would use an Object Class with properties to contain the individual item types you need.

Create a web page/windows form etc. that loads the data for each of the Object's properties on screen, allowing the user to alter the data (text, numbers, images etc.).

Store these values in the Object Instance and then Serialize it (as Binary or XML for example), and save to a file.

You could then load the file and De-Serialize it into the Object Instance again, to display and allow editing.

However, just after seeing your edit...

How would a user edit an image in a text file? Are you certain that you will be storing Serialized data in a file that a user can edit manually?

Even using a zip file, the user could completely break any structure you may think is there. If you could expand on what they are storing and what part of the data they can edit and what those edits consist of, it might be easier to see your problem.

Comment: Well, i'm the kinda guy, if the user breaks something on his own, then it's not the fault of the system and neither mine. But you approach might be fitting for a DAU (dumbest assumed user) approach, i actually think a user is capable of manipulating data without breaking stuff ;)

Answer (score 0):

When i need a "savefile" like this,first i store the type of the object in 1 byte, and then the object length in 4 bytes (binary int), and then the entire object in binary. If you want, you could add encryption on top of the serialized object and just code that in to your reader.

The `System.IO.BinaryWriter` and `System.IO.BinaryReader` are excellent for this.

First convert an int to 4 bytes, write it to your savefile, convert a enum value of the objecttype you are saving to a byte, write it to the file, then write the serialized object.

When opening the saved objects, just start at the beginning of the savefile, and you know you need to read 4 bytes to get the object length, one byte to get the type, and then just read as many bytes as you first read for length. Once done reading that object, the pointer in the savefile will be at a new 4 byte integer for the next object.
Continue untill you reach the end of the file, and there you go :)

Comment: This will result in a _binary_ file which is no longer editable in a simple way (e.g. a text editor)

Comment: This would not fit the requirement that the user should be able to manipulate/edit the data, with me providing a separate editor.

Comment: Manipulating the data with this solution should still be performed in your project, not directly on the file. If that is what you require for editing, im not quite sure how you should store images :-\ But if you code the editor, you open the file the same way, edit the objects in your editor, and save it the same way.

Comment: This would be a solution for things that have many failure points, but I've already designed fallback's if anything goes sideways. But it wont completely prevent corrupted data, if the user does something wrong. But that's actually not my problem ;)

Comment: Then XML or JSON is probably the way to go. With Base encoded images. The file would then be very readable in any texteditor. Just change the writer from a binary writer, to write json data instead. There are parsers for json and xml scattered around google :)

Comment: Images aren't that easy to manipulate while in string form, i.e. still doesn't fit the requirements stated within the remarks.